# Laravel Debugbar Not Showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, phpdebugbar

I have a project with Laravel version 7.28. I run

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev,
```

After that I added `Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class` to `app/config.php` under providers and added

```
'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class
```

to `app/config.php` under aliases. Then I run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"
```

Even though `APP_DEBUG` in `.env` is `true` and I terminated and rerun the app debugbar is not showing. Where did I make my mistake?

Comment: make sure you cleared caches: "php artisan config:cache"

Comment: @boolfalse yes, i already run ````php artisan optimize:clear``` but it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: is this a typo "app/config.php" ? There should be "config/app.php"

Comment: also run "composer dump-autoload"

Comment: @boolfalse yes, that was a typo. i run composer dump-autoload but it didn't work. any other thoughts?

Comment: Does anything discussed at https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/870 resolve the issue?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper unfortunately no, i looked at that issue first but it didn't help

Comment: Debugbar works only in `Development` mode so please check `APP_ENV` because it must be `locale` and `APP_DEBUG` must be `true`

Answer (score 1):

I checked the config/debugbar.php, I see the new key DEBUGBAR_ENABLED with default is false. Then add it to .env file: `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=true`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running on right port. I had php backend (running on port 8000) and react frontend (running on port 3000) and I did everything you have described above but it never worked. The issue I had was that I was checking if the debugbar showed up on port 3000 (which it never did sadly). I went to check on port 8000 and the debugbar was sitting there the whole time.

I didn't end up using the php debugbar because I think it only works if your frontend code is written in php (though not 100% sure).

I ended up debugging using [postman](https://www.postman.com/). It doesn't have all the functionalities that the debugbar offers but it is a great tool to use if you just want to do basic debugging.